# How to trace what happens to a DOM Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using the [masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for a web app at work. I'm applying masks using a class selector in `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(".Primary_Phone_Number").mask("(999) 999-9999");
$(".ZipCodeMask").mask("99999");
$(".StateMask").mask("aa");
$(".date").mask("99/99/9999");
```

However, everything except the Phone number is losing it's mask. After document ready, if I run these again in the console, they get and retain their mask.

It's a large web app, each page has 1000s of lines of javascript and there are a lot of diverse selectors flying around making changes as well as a lot of ajax calls. We're only testing the web app in IE since it's an internal project. Is there anything available in IE10 to let me know when a particular DOM Element is getting manipulated?

Comment: Does the behaviour happen in Chrome, Firefox, or Opera? If so, you could debug there and test back in IE.

Comment: The app as a whole only works in IE. We have not supported any other browser since day one. I've tried it in Chrome and stuff starts failing left and right.

Comment: In other browsers, instead of `GET` or `POST`, all the AJAX happens as `OPTIONS`. We've never looked into a fix because we aren't supporting them.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome (and you can use it for debugging, if the problem reproduces), you can put a breakpoint on DOM modification.

Inspect the element, right click on it, choose "Break on..." and choose the event type (e.g. subtree modification). [More info on this](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-mutation-events).

If you still want to do it in IE (9+), you can use [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and break the JS execution when the element is modified.

E.g.

```js
el.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(ev) {
  debugger;
}. false);
```